# Position div next to mouse, but with in div

Tags: jquery, css, position

I'm using the following code to position `mousediv` next to where the mouse is clicked.

```
$("#item").click(function(e) {
    $('#mousediv').css({ 'top': e.pageY -50,'left': e.pageX -10, 'position':'absolute' }).show()
})
```

This works well and the DIV is shown near to the mouse.

The link I am clicking on is within a div called `wrapper` when the new div is shown it can overflow out of this div.

Is there anyway to show `mousediv` next to where the mouse is clicked but give it limits so it can't leave the wrapper div ?

Thanks

Comment: Determine the top/bottom(y) and left/right(x) positions of the wrapper and adjust `top` accordingly, eg using [max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) or [min()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/) along with either [.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) or [.min()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)

Working sample:

```js
$("#item").click(function(e) {
console.log($('.wrapper-div').position());
  $('#mousediv').css({
    'top': Math.max($('.wrapper-div').position().top, 50),
    'left': Math.max($('.wrapper-div').position().left, 30),
    'position': 'absolute'
  }).show()
})
```

```css
.wrapper-div {
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper-div">
  <a href="javascript::viod(0);" id="item">Click Here</a>
  <div id="mousediv">Look I am changing!</div>
</div>
<br/>
```

Comment: Thanks that has helped me resolve an issue :)

Comment: @Dr.Alivetodie-Anant Thank you. I've managed to use this to fix my problem.